# set button to selected on reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selected

I want to set my button to selected if it meets proper condition.
I tried similar option with disabled and it works but for selected i am having hard time , any help will be awesome.

`return <Button key={obj[0]} className="btn btn-block" onClick={this.select_slot.bind(this,value,obj[0])} ref="delivery_slot_id" disabled={obj[2]=="full"} selected={this.props.values==this.props.grocery_cart.delivery_date&&obj[0]==this.props.grocery_cart.delivery_slot_id}>{obj[1]}<br/>  </Button>`

The this.props.value gives a string for eg "a"
and the this.props.grocery_cart.delivery_date is on a loop; so returns ,for eg "a" to "z"

in the loop if a == a , the selected should work.

This may not be the correct way , if any better way , please do suggest.

Comment: I'm assuming `<Button>` is from React-Bootstrap. If so, be aware that it doesn't have a `selected` property.

Comment: Yes the Button is a react Bootstrap, Thank you for the Hint.